# What's the best way to use multiple PHP classes?

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I have looked on this website for similar questions and found some useful resources but could someone help me out with this...

I'm using PDO to connect to a MySQL database. I want to make use of classes and have a basic understanding of them.

Firstly, am I going about things in the right way by having a db class that takes care of the connection to the database?

Secondly, I want other classes (in seperate files) for my users, messages, photos etc. My problem/question is - how can these classes share the db connection that has already been established and query the database???

I appreciate any feedback and useful code.

Thanks

Comment: Some people (like my friend) think database classes are redundant, but I can't tell you how much time I saved only having to change one `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query`, etc, rather than having to go through *all* my files and change every single one.

Comment: @animuson: Your friend wouldn't happen to have mentions of currency in his username, would he?

Answer (score 1):

If you've established a database connection at the top of your main script file, which handles the actual logic, then you can use `include` on the other classes. They'll be able to access the same variables so long as you reference them properly given their scope, and they'll all be sharing the same connection. If you define `$db` at the very top and have included other files below, they'll all be able to access that `$db`.

Comment: Is there even any point in a class for the PDO? Would it be better just to connect to the DB in an include file and then each class could  query the database somehow (i assume by making the connection handle global)

Comment: @user1003632: Yes, because you can change things more easily if you decide you don't like the way something works.

Comment: So i guess it's a toss up between using Globals and Singletons

Answer (score 1):

If you create a db object from the db class, and want to access it inside another class, yone way is to reference globals.

```
Class db {
   ...some code creading your pdo...
}

$db = new db();

Class page {
   function __construct(){
      global $db; //Tell this function to use the global version of $db
      ... you can now use the db connection in this function...
   }
}

$page = new page();
```

As long as the db class is included in the same page (not always the same file, but the same page load from a viewers perspective), before you create the page() object, then you will have $db in the global scope.

Comment: Yes but if I have a PHP file that requires the Users class and the Messages class they will both make a connection to the database unnecessarily won't they?

Comment: The connection is only made when you create a new db() object, not each time you reference it. If you create a new db() as $db, followed by a new User() and new Message(), you can access the $db variable inside user and message using 'global $db'. It is a reference to the already existing connection class, it does not create a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `include_once("db_class");` to add the db class to any other class/file that needs it, here you make a different database connection anytime the class is included. If are you trying to use a single database connection, you should learn about persistent connections.